# Error catched by then instead of catch of Promise - React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, promise

I am having a problem when calling two async functions in React Native.

Here is code (I just changed the names):

```js
   getItems()
      .then((response) => {
        setItems(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('getItems', err));

    getOtherItems()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response.data', response.data);
        setOtherItems(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('getOtherItems', err));
```

When the first function throws an error, the error is correctly catched by the `catch`. But, when the second functions breaks, the error passes through `then` instead of catch.

The logs are like this:

```sh
getItems <Error>
response.data <Error>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT:

`getItems` and `getOtherItems` make an HTTP call using `axios` to an external service that returns an array of items.

EDIT 2:

Code for `getItems` and `getOtherItems`:

```js
 getItems() {
    return axios.get('an URL');
  }

  getOtherItems() {
    return axios.get('another URL');
  }
```

EDIT 3:

I realized the first function throws a 500 error while the second logs a 404. So, the problem may be with how the services return the error.

EDIT 4:

It seems the problem is an error in the service. I'll let you know once it's confirmed. Thanks!

Comment: what does `getOtherItems` do?

Comment: If you return an error from a rejection listener (i.e. catch), it will be propagated as the resolved value.

Comment: `getOtherItems` does something similar to `getItems`, they make a HTTP call using `axios` to a service that returns an array of items.

Comment: @TimTimWong I understand, but I'm not returning the error. The two functions make two separate calls with their respective then/catch.

Comment: Can you show the actual code?

Comment: I can show you the axios call, the problem is that the code is from my work and I can't show the real thing. I'll edit the question adding the axios call.

Comment: if you're hitting `then` instead of `catch`, no error got _thrown_ (i.e. no `throw new Error(...)` occurred anywhere in the code you called) , it looks like the method you called instead _returned_ an Error object, in which case it's treated like any other normal data and gets forwarded to your promise resolution handler.

Comment: Are you sure that the first error is being thrown in `getItems` and not `setItems`? What is the actual error?

Comment: @JLRishe I'll edit the question to show you the exact log.

Comment: @eldercookie try this in your catch `if( error.response ){console.log(error.response.data);}` maybe it's an axios issue and it's related to [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/376)

Comment: It seems the problem in inside the service. Once fixed I'll let you know more details. Thanks!.